# Confirmation of the correctness of this new method of integration.

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to know if the following method of integration works, and also how to finish the solution if one can see how. I just thought of it myself. Please feel free to point out any flaws in it. I do not want alternatives given though if you think this is 'inefficient'. I am only interested in the correctness of this method.

Given an integral of the form, $\int (f(x)\mod a) dx$ do the following:

$$\left(\int f(x) dx\right) \mod a = \left(\int \bigl(f(x) \mod a\bigr)dx\right) \mod a$$

$$F(x) \mod a = \left(\int \bigl(f(x) \mod a\bigr)dx\right) \mod a$$

$$F(x) - a\left\lfloor \frac {F(x)}a \right\rfloor = \int \bigl(f(x) \mod a\bigr)dx - a\left\lfloor \frac {\int \bigl(f(x) \mod a\bigr)dx}a \right\rfloor$$

I am not sure how to progress in the integration process from here. Can someone help. I believe that something involving the additive separation property for modulo will allow an integration method to prosper. I'm just unsure of *what* exactly to do.

Comment: It is unclear what kind of function $f$ is, what kind of number $a$ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method doesn't appear to work. Counterexample, for $a=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$:

$$\left(\int_{0}^{3} x^2 \;dx\right) \bmod 1 = 3 \bmod 1 = 0$$

$$\left(\int_{0}^{3} (x^2 \bmod 1) \;dx\right) \bmod 1 = (-12+3 \sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5+\sqrt6+\sqrt7 \approx 1.3) \bmod 1 \approx 0.3 \ne 0$$

Since the definite integrals on the same interval differ, the antiderivatives cannot be equal.

Comment: You are right about the problem. As to the evaluation, it's just by breaking it down by intervals $[0,1), [1,\sqrt 2), [\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3), ...\;$ where $x^2 \bmod 1$ is a constant.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Right, of course. Should have been "*where* $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ *is a constant*".